# Future<dynamic> is not a subtype of "Widget"

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to display the data as list of widgets but I encountered an error `Future<dynamic>` is not a subtype of `Widget`. Please also check is my `getData()` method if it is correct?

1. `getData()` function:

```dart
    getData() async {
      final data = await Firestore.instance
        .collection('lisofprods')
        .document('ac1').get();

      DocumentSnapshot snapshot = data.data['name'];
      print(snapshot);
      return ListTile(
        title: Text("$snapshot"),
      );
    }
```

2. Widget

```dart
    Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            getData(),//here is the error 
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Can you please the error log? Your getData has an error. You need to declare that your `data` variable is a `DocumentSnapshot`. And then the `data.data['name']` you are trying to extract will be a `String`.

Comment: not able to upload logs here lines are limited

Comment: Check my answer below with a working version of your code with a FutureBuilder.

Comment: If my answer below is correct, as you said, please mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 4):

This is not the proper way to get widget after u got the data, what is happening here is , getData is Async method and you are waiting for the result before returning the widget....

You need to use FutureBuilder :
Widget that builds itself based on the latest snapshot of interaction with a Future

For detailed info :[FutureBuilder](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ek8ZPdWj4Qo)

Answer (score 4):

**Function**

```
Future<String> getData() async {
  final DocumentSnapshot data = await Firestore.instance
    .collection('lisofprods')
    .document('ac1').get();

  String name = data.data['name'];

  return name;
}
```

**Widget**

```
FutureBuilder(
  future: getData(),
  builder: (context, snapshot){
    return ListTile(
      title: Text("${snapshot.data.toString()}"),
    );
  },
),
```

Check this for full implementation of `FutureBuilder` https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

Answer (score 2):

As your "getData()" function marked async, it only returns type "Future". 
Use [Future Builder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) to achieve the thing